# Array from values and order definition object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

using TypeScript I want to create an array of values using an order definition object.

Suppose the following example:

- **values** are table column `headers`
- **order** is the requested `order` of these columns

Types:

```js
type H = {title: string, description: string};
type O = { [key in keyof H]: number };
```

```js
const headers: H = {
 description: 'Description',
 title: 'Title',
}
```

```js
const order: O = {
 title: 0,
 description: 1,
}
```

(let's suppose, that values in `order` are always "normalized" to be valid array indices (they are unique positive intigers in consecutive order starting from 0)

I want the following output:

```js
['Title', 'Description']
```

I hoped that the below would work:

```js
mapToArray = (headers: H, order: O): string[] => {
    let result: string[] = [];
    for (let k in headers) {
      result[order[k]] = headers[k];
    }

    return result;
  }
```

however, I get the following error:

```
Type 'H[Extract<keyof H, string>]' is not assignable to type 'string[][O[Extract<keyof H, string>]]'.
  Type 'H' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Type 'H[Extract<keyof H, string>]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'H[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

ts compiler options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "tslint-language-service"
      }
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es2017.object",
      "es2016.array.include"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "build",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
```

Comment: when title is 9 and description is 1, why your desired out put is `['Title', 'Description']`?

Comment: @RezaRahmati sorry typo - the `9` should be `0`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that right now, the TS compiler assumes that the `k` variable in your `for` loop is a `string`.

Just let it know that it is a key of `H`:

```
type H = {title: string, description: string};
type O = { [key in keyof H]: number };

const headers: H = {
 description: 'Description',
 title: 'Title',
}

const order: O = {
 title: 0,
 description: 1,
}

const mapToArray = (headers: H, order: O): string[] => {
    let result: string[] = [];
    let k: keyof H;
    for (k in headers) {
      result[order[k]] = headers[k];
    }

    return result;
  }
```

*Update*: I also took over @RezaRahmati's tip, correcting the definition of `O`, which threw an unrelated error.

[See on TS Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAElC8UDewCWwA2EBcUDOwATqgHYDmANFACYR4DGxYaA9ibgceQL4DcAUKEhQA8gmRQA2gGsIIKKSiyQLAGawAurhIBXALYAjCISh9+-emwJQAFhACGtQnlxxESfjTqNUzVG1wAcgARbyZWEkCKTzRMHChAgBV0LCj+bnNLEmsWQidcMXcYlPiABmivBnD-digARmiMiytgKD17MESWAEFCQnt5RAAKO0djF1gqXPzRAEoOIlIySQ0EAD5kTyhtrFbCOh0MYAWuZdXEFYFtnYhW6VxlNVgr69VcqCHpBRJbByc8Waba7XfZ4Q7ASTTYwyDTnX5jZwwl7bJrA-bAHSEH6g8EvbhAA)

Comment: This makes sense. I'm surprised it didn't solve the problem. It only changed the first line of the error to: `Type 'H[keyof H]' is not assignable to type 'string[][O[keyof H]]'.`

Comment: The code I pasted compiles without any problem with the default `tsc` options (alas: no options) and in the playground. If it does not for you, can you share your `tsconfig.json`?

Comment: I updated the question with my compiler options, I don't find any of them could make the difference. (I use TS 3.5.2). Also, I noticed that in the playground, when I turn on `noLib` option, I get some (different) error on the lines in question.

Comment: I am using tsc 3.5.2 and your tsconfig.json, and it still compiles just fine.

Comment: Also, why would you want to turn `noLib` on?

Comment: Oh OK, my bad: My simplified example here is indeed actually correct. The error was caused by `H` is in actual code a generic type parameter to a wrapper class and `string` values of `H` weren't inferred the way they are in the type `H` definition in the example. Not sure how to approach this case on SO. Should I delete or close the Q or respecify it and provide my own answer?

Answer (score 0):

I just created a stackblitz and no issue

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-56954561-array-from-values-and-order-definition-object

The only change I made

```
type O = { [key in keyof H]: number };
```

Comment: The `T` instead of `H` was also a typo, thanks for pointing out. However, I'm not sure where to find the TS compiler output on stackblitz. I believe they suppress some TS compiler output, that would be why it works there. I cannot change my tsconfig though.

Comment: I guess this is it https://github.com/stackblitz/angular-cli-template/blob/master/tsconfig.json

Comment: @Kizivat you have to exercise copy-paste more to avoid typos ;D